# Appcelerator marquee text

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, marquee

I would like to do horizontal sliding dynamic text. Text should be one line and move from right to left. I tried this code, but it works only with Android 2.3.7, not with Android 4.2.2. I am using Alloy.

[image: text scrolling in blue strip]

```
    // width of label in dp    
    var labelWidthDP = $.slidingTextView.toImage().width / (Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.dpi / 160);
    // width of device screen in dp 
    var screenWidthDP = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth / (Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.dpi / 160);

    var animation = Titanium.UI.createAnimation({
        left: -(labelWidthDP),
        duration:2000,
        curve: Titanium.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_LINEAR
    });

    animation.addEventListener('complete',function() {
         $.slidingTextLabel.left = screenWidthDP;
         $.slidingTextLabel.animate(animation); 
     });

     $.slidingTextLabel.animate(animation);
```

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: in android native textview have property like this android:ellipsize="marquee"

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the similar questions asked in [Titanium Q & A](https://developer.appcelerator.com/questions/newest).

For your question I think following would help :

- [How to create a like Marquee in Titanium with continuos mode](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/143419/how-to-create-a-like-marquee-in-titanium-with-continous-mode#answer-249165)
- [Horizontal scrolling text](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/143128/horizontal-scrolling-text)